# ActiveRecord and jRuby threads/fibers (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, celluloid

I'm using jRuby and Celluloid (default task_class so it should be fibers).

I am wrapping my DB stuff in ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection, but it's possible I might have missed it somewhere (how to find that out anyway?).

I sometimes get ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError errors, and I want to avoid this. In theory my database.yml pool setting should be high enough for the amount of threads that I have.

What's the proper way to use ActiveRecord in (real) threading situations? If possible I would love to avoid ActiveRecord automatically checking out connections when I don't explicitly use ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection. Note that this is a background app, not a traditional Rails app which would serve web clients.

I am using jRuby and Rails 4 rc1. For DB I am using a production-level Postgres on Heroku, so performance of DB should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying your app on Heroku (which I am assuming here, as you are using Heroku Postgres) then your database.yml file will be overwritten when you deploy your app.

Heroku injects a new database.yml that is designed to parse the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, so none of your settings would apply in production.

There is an article about this in the [Heroku Devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#connection-pool).

Essentially you need to update the active record configuration and re-establish the connection after your app has loaded. A nice benefit of that approach is that you can easily change your connection pool without doing an additional deploy, you simply run:

`heroku config:add DB_POOL=24`

And the app gets restarted with the new pool level.

Comment: Although this is good info, it doesn't apply. I am not hosting on Heroku (except the DB). Thanks anyway though.